# iOS: Cannot install app as IPA

Tags: ios, deployment, ipa

I followed the steps to create an IPA of my app and would like to install via iTunes. After importing to library, I can see my app listed in the Apps section and a button says "Will Install" is on the right side of the list item. Also the app's icon appears in the iOS desktop view.

However, after clicking sync, which gave no errors, the app does not show itself on the desktop of the device.

I tried to deploy directly using Xcode's organizer and that worked fine.
I also tried to drag my provisioning profile into iTunes to no avail.

What am I missing here?

I'm using iTunes 11.0.2, Xcode4.6.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also tried distributing my app through iTunes to beta testers, but I didn't succeed- always had errors and errors.

Use the iPhone Configuration Utility for [Mac OS X](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465) or for [Windows](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1466)- this works auto-magically, with no errors.
Guaranteed.